# Need for doctrine in CI

Tags: activerecord, doctrine-orm, codeigniter-2

I have been using CI since last 6 months and recently I stumbled upon an ORM Doctrine.
Now as far as I am using CI I guessed it gave almost all the required functionality that I needed using `active records`.
So can please some one tell what are the plus points of using doctrine above active records.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from my point of view working with Active records should do the trick.
for more information also check the bellow links

http://mackstar.com/blog/2010/07/29/doctrine-2-and-why-you-should-use-it

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/227999/